# reactJS: convert from “yyyy-mm-ddThh-mm-ss.sssZ” to “yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to convert following string "2021-06-11T11:23:00.000Z" to "2021-06-11T11:23" in reactjs?

Comment: `"2021-06-11T11:23:00.000Z".substr(0, 16)`

Comment: I would recommend to use `moment` https://momentjs.com/  library when it comes to Date related stuff.

Comment: Your title says that your target format is yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm but the actual question shows yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm! Which one is it.

Comment: @Goutham Although moment is great at this kind of stuff, I wouldn't recommend it for "new" work as it has effectively been deprecated. Even the project recommend using another library like Luxon.

Comment: Thanks @phuzi . Never heard of `Luxon` before, I will try to explore it from now.